# Populate a field with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Ok guys,

I'm working on a movie app to practice my angular and node skills. I'm using mongoose to work with my database and at the moment I'm looking into 'populate'.
I have the following user schema and I was wondering how I could populate the objects in my `ratings` key. `ratings` is an array of objects, these objects look like this `{movie:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}, rating:Number}`. I was wondering how I could populate the movie key of every object in that array. The structure in the node route document I think should look like below, but I don't know what to enter in `.populate()`.

```
User.find({'_id':someNumber).populate(noIdeaWhatToWriteHere).exec()
```

**user.js model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var mongooseUniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');


var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique:true},
    ratings: [{movie:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}, rating:Number}],
    reviews: [{movie:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}, review:String}]
}, { usePushEach: true });

schema.plugin(mongooseUniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to keep in mind is that the name in populate has to go in plural.

```
User.find({'_id':someNumber).populate('movies').exec()
```

Comment: I tried it, but it returned { movie: 5a6b16485970c21cbc5bf2b3, rating: 4 }, so it didn't get populated.

Comment: Have you tried with Movies ??  Maybe is case sensitive. You have to write it in the populate method the same way is written the collection name

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I used .populate('ratings.movie') and now it worked.